# Can we also segment out the region detected by haar cascade classifier?

Tags: opencv3.0, image-segmentation, object-detection, haar-classifier

I am trying to train a haar cascade classifier so that it can detect trees in an image. After detection the classifier is expected to draw a bounding rectangle around the object. I need to now segment out this region that is enclosed within the bounding box. I would like to know if this is a possible way for segmentation of tree from its background or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitly possible to segment out the area enclosed with the boundings of the box, just write `Mat <new name> = name ( <vector>[] )`
Where - 
Name - the name of your original frame which a detection is running on.
New name - the cropped area name.
Vector - the vector of detected object.

It worked for me very well, I hope it is useful for you too.